# How can I segue from one UIWebView to another with an html link in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ViewControllers with a UIWebView in each. I would like to click a link in one UIWebView and segue to the other ViewController or UIWebView.

How can I segue from one UIWebView to another with an html link in Swift?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be careful with your terminology. You can't segue from a view or to a view, you can only segue from a view controller to another view controller. You can intercept a click on a link in a web view with the UIWebView delegate method, 
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType. In that method, you can check if the URL from the link clicked on was the one you're interested in, segue to another controller, and return NO, so the web view doesn't try to load that URL.